# How do i change the individual color of RectangleMark in my candle stick chart according to open and close price in Swift Charts

Tags: ios, swiftui, state, candlestick-chart, swiftui-charts

[this is what i get when i try to change the color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmmBE.png) sorry can't post image here yet so i suggested to use link

I used RectangleMark from apple `Charts` Api
here is my chart, my chartData has low, high, open, and close prices
I want to have it to look like a normal `candle stick chart`, red when it is down, green when it is up using the open and close price value

I made a @State chartColor to have it changed with func to trigger it, but I get all of the chart red instead of a proper `candle stick chart`

Here is my code

```
import SwiftUI
import Charts
struct CoinChart: View {
    @ObservedObject var chartManager: ChartManager
    @State var chartColor: Color
    

func colorChange(){
    for content in chartManager.chartData.data {
        
        let openPrice = Double(content.open)
        let closePrice = Double(content.close)
        if closePrice! < openPrice! {
            chartColor = Color.red
        } else {
            chartColor = Color.green
        }
    }
}
var body: some View {
    
    VStack {
        
        Chart{
            ForEach(chartManager.chartData.data, id: \.self) { chartData in
                
                let date = chartManager.unixConverter(unixTime: Double(chartData.period))
                let dates = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(chartData.period))
                let lowPrice = Double(chartData.low)
                let highPrice = Double(chartData.high)
                let openPrice = Double(chartData.open)
                let closePrice = Double(chartData.close)
                RectangleMark(x: .value("Time", date),
                              yStart: .value("Low Price", lowPrice!),
                              yEnd: .value("High Price", highPrice!), width: 1)
                .foregroundStyle(chartColor)
                
                RectangleMark(x: .value("Time", date),
                              yStart: .value("Open Price", openPrice!),
                              yEnd: .value("Close Price", closePrice!), width: 6)
                .foregroundStyle(chartColor)

            }
        }
        
        .chartYScale(domain: 18000...21000)
        .chartXAxis {
            AxisMarks(position: .bottom) { _ in
                AxisGridLine().foregroundStyle(.clear)
                AxisTick().foregroundStyle(.clear)
                AxisValueLabel()
                
            }
        }
        
        .frame(height: 300)
        
        Text(String(chartManager.chartData.data.count))
        
    }
    .task {
        await chartManager.loadChartData()
        colorChange()
    }
}
}
```

I called the `func colorChange()` in the task cuz if I call it in the chart it will give me a purple warning

```
Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior.
```

Any help will be appreciated everyone?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do yourself a favour and stop constantly doing this: `let lowPrice = Double(chartData.low)` etc...
Make `chartData.low` etc... `Double` to start with.

Comment: have you tried using this: `.foregroundStyle(closePrice! < openPrice! ? .red : .green)`, instead of your `colorChange()` thing.

Comment: hey man, i am sorry if my code is messy, quite new to this, trying to figure my way out 
the whole chartdata.low etc are returned from api call, they r all in string value for some reason, and i dunno how to convert them to double other than the way i was doing it

Comment: hey @workingdogsupportUkraine it worked man, Jesus i can't believe how stupid i was 
again i thank you for your help

Comment: how do i mark your comment as an accepted answer?

Comment: glad it worked, don't worry about the accepted answer, thanks anyway. Why are your values String type? You 
read them as Doubles (from your previous post). If you really need to convert them to Doubles, and 
I really doubt you have to, then do it as you read them, or just after, then you are good to go with Doubles after that.

Comment: hey, you still remember that haha 
yes, it was double, but the JSON was in a very strange kinda format, where I had to read the data in the array using indices, to make the chart I realized I have manipulate the range of the data, but I was not able to do so using the prev dataset, I found a new API that allows me to do that and better structured, but somehow the data values are in String type